# Docker Swarm: how to update published post

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I use the Play-with-Docker platform to create a Swarm cluster with 3 Docker instances: 1 manager and 2 workers; then I create a service from the image `nginx:alpine`:

```
docker service create -p 8080:80 --name nginx-app nginx:alpine
```

Things worked fine.

Then I `update` the service to change the published port: instead of `8080`, now I want the published port to be `8081`. I ran this:

```
docker service update --publish-rm 8080 --publish-add 8081 nginx-app
```

But it did not remove the published port `8080`; instead it created another published port `30002`, this port `30002` mapped to `8081`

[image]

What did I do wrong here? How can I change the published port?

Answer (score 6):

The `--publish-rm` option takes the target port, not the published port:

```
docker service update --publish-rm 80 --publish-add 8081:80 nginx-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove those services and start it like this instead:

`docker service create -p 8081:80 --name nginx-app nginx:alpine`